# How do I store persistent user preferences in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, user-input, outlook-addin

I'm writing a relatively complex outlook add-in, and would like to have an initial setup process before storing user's choices. What's considered best practice?

Off the top of my head I could write a file somewhere, or maybe use the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Project Settings and set the scope to "User"

[image]

So if you had a setting called "myOutputLocation" you would refer it in your code like:

```
Dim myLoc As String = My.Settings.myOutputLocation
```

Similarly, you can assign persistent values back to it with:

```
My.Settings.myOutputLocation = someUserGeneratedString
```

---

Note that when you debug, the settings are temporary and do not write back to the actual project - but in live they will be persistent.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do not use User-scoped settings in an Outlook add-in.  Technically they are not supported - although they do work. To a point!  When Outlook is patched or upgraded it creates a new version numbered folder where the user.config file is stored, and calling Settings.Upgrade does not work reliably. I've also seen situations where the entire Settings system becomes unusable.  Suffice it to say I've moved towards always using a custom Settings provider.